# Make first row selected when use DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf

I know there are other questions regarding how to make first row selected but I tried the following code:

```
fileDataGrid.Focus();
fileDataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;

var item = fileDataGrid.Items[0];

fileDataGrid.SelectedItem = item;
fileDataGrid.SelectedItems.Clear();
fileDataGrid.SelectedItems.Add(item);
```

If I want to navigate in that data grid to second row, I have to press twice DOWN key: because first, the grid header/column somehow is focused and then selects first cell of first row.

I want, when press DOWN key, to navigate to second row automatically.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is I have created a common function which select the desired cell

```
/// <summary>
    /// This method selects a cell in the Lines datagrid and begins editing it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataGrid"></param>
    /// <param name="column"></param>
    /// <param name="rowItem"></param>
    private void SelectCell(DataGrid dataGrid, DataGridColumn column, Object rowItem)
    {
        if (rowItem != null)
        {
            DataGridCellInfo cellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(rowItem, column);
            if (dataGrid.CurrentCell.Item != cellInfo.Item || dataGrid.CurrentCell.Column != cellInfo.Column)
            {
                dataGrid.Focus();
                dataGrid.CurrentCell = cellInfo;
                dataGrid.SelectedIndex = dataGrid.Items.IndexOf(rowItem);
            }
            else
            {
                dataGrid.Focus();
                dataGrid.CurrentCell = cellInfo;
                dataGrid.SelectedIndex = dataGrid.Items.IndexOf(rowItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

Xaml as follows

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="Lines" PreviewKeyDown="Lines_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

in Xaml.cs

```
private void Lines_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
             switch (e.Key)
            {
                case Key.Up:                        
                    isBeginingEdit = false;
                    e.Handled = true;
                    return;
                case Key.Down:
                    SelectCell(Lines, Lines.Columns[0], Lines.SelectedItem);
                    e.Handled = true;
                    return;
            }
    }
```

Hope it will help

Comment: It not working for me, I mean when press DOWN key, the grid is always focused, the 2nd row (as I expected) is not selected

Comment: why this is needed 'fileDataGrid.Focus();' ? It is focusing the grid itself

Comment: I made it working with example: http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html